# А как дергать системные вызовы из C?

Tags: linux, c, компиляция

Как напрямую использовать системные вызовы из C, при `-nostdlib`? Код:

```
int main() {
    write(1, "It works\n", 10);
    return 0;
}
```

```
 ~ $ gcc print.c -nostdlib
ld.lld: undefined symbol write
```

Постойте, `write()` же системный вызов... Тот же ассемблер все системные вызовы осуществляет без библиотек (даже статических, ну а иначе не было бы этих ваших реверс шеллов на 237 байт). Так а на более простом и родном C или C++ как это сделать-то?

Comment: Вот статья ещё есть https://the-linux-channel.the-toffee-project.org/index.php?page=5-tutorials-a-linux-system-call-in-c-without-a-standard-library&lang=en

Comment: один чёрт нужен ассемблер(((